# Using RegEx in c# to check for valid characters

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having a hard time understand regex.  I have a scenario where valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and a space.  So when I try and create a RegEx for invalid characters I have this, [^a-zA-Z0-9 ].
Then I have strings that I want to search based on the RegEx and when it finds an invalid character, it checks if the character before it is invalid.
for example, "test test +?test"
So what I want to happen is if there are two invalid characters, one after the other, do nothing otherwise insert a '£'.  So the string above will be fine, no changes.  However, the string, "test test £test", should be changed to "test test ££test".

This is my code..

```
public string HandleInvalidChars(string message)
    {
        const string methodName = "HandleInvalidChars";

        Regex specialChars = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]");
        string strSpecialChars = specialChars.ToString();

        //prev character in string which we are going to check 
        string prevChar;

        Match match = specialChars.Match(message); 

        while (match.Success) 
        {

            //get position of special character
            int position = match.Index;

            // get character before special character
            prevChar = message.Substring(position - 1, 1);

            //check if next character is a special character, if not insert ? escape character
            try
            {
                if (!Regex.IsMatch(prevChar, strSpecialChars))
                {

                    message = message.Insert(position, "?");

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.ErrorFormat("{0}: ApplicationException: {1}", methodName, ex);
                return message;
            }


            match = match.NextMatch();
            //loop through remainder of string until last character

        }

        return message;
    }
```

When I test it on the first string it handles the first invalid char, '+', ok but it falls over when it reaches '£'.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, whats that for? ``const string methodName = "HandleInvalidChars``

Comment: It's for the catch statement, when there is an error..its prints out the method name and then the error to the log file

Comment: have you tried using a cheat sheet yet? http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/courses/27610/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-v2.pdf

Comment: You could use ``[CallerMemberName]`` attribute. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx, but thats another story.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/bct6hu - is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Is my solution doing what you need to get in the end?

Answer (score 0):

What if you would change the RegEx to something like below, to check for only those cases with one special character and not with two?

```
[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{0,1}[^a-zA-Z0-9 ][a-zA-Z0-9 ]{0,1}
```

Another thing, I would create a new variable for the return value. As I can see you are keep changing the original string where you are looking for matches.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have overthought it a bit. All you need is to find a forbidden char that is not preceded nor followed with another forbidden char.

Declare

```
public string HandleInvalidChars(string message)
{
    var pat = @"(?<![^A-Za-z0-9 ])[^A-Za-z0-9 ](?![^A-Za-z0-9 ])";
    return Regex.Replace(message, pat, "£$&");
}
```

and use:

```
Console.WriteLine(HandleInvalidChars("test test £test"));
// => test test ££test
Console.WriteLine(HandleInvalidChars("test test +?test"));
// => test test +?test
```

See the [online C# demo](https://ideone.com/Omj44l).

**Details**

- `(?<![^A-Za-z0-9 ])` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a char other than an ASCII letter/digit or space immediately to the left of the current location
- `[^A-Za-z0-9 ]` - a char other than an ASCII letter/digit or space
- `(?![^A-Za-z0-9 ])`  - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a char other than an ASCII letter/digit or space immediately to the right of the current location.

The replacement string contains a `$&`, backreference to the whole match value. Thus, using `"£$&"` we insert a `£` before the match.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5b%5eA-Za-z0-9%5cr%5cn+%5d%29%5b%5eA-Za-z0-9%5cr%5cn+%5d%28%3f!%5b%5eA-Za-z0-9%5cr%5cn+%5d%29&i=test+test+%c2%a3test%0d%0atest+test+%2b%3ftest&r=%c2%a3).

[image]